# What does the aptitude `why` and `why-not` mean?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, aptitude

From the manuals:

> The command why finds a dependency chain that installs the package
>   named on the command line, as above. Note that the dependency that
>   aptitude produced in this case is only a suggestion. This is because
>   no package currently installed on this computer depends on or
>   recommends the kdepim package; if a stronger dependency were
>   available, aptitude would have displayed it.
>
> In contrast, why-not finds a dependency chain leading to a conflict
>   with the target package:

In my case(`Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l`), I'm trying to install `libdbus-1-3:i386`

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.10) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried `aptitude why` and `aptitude why-not`, hoping to get more information about why the installation failed.

```
$ sudo aptitude why libdbus-1-3:i386
p   upstart:i386 Provides upstart                     
p   upstart:i386 Depends  libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.2.16)

$ sudo aptitude why-not libdbus-1-3:i386
Unable to find a reason to remove libdbus-1-3:i386.

$ sudo aptitude why libc6:i386
p   sqlite3:i386 Provides sqlite3            
p   sqlite3:i386 Depends  libc6:i386 (>= 2.4)

$ sudo aptitude why-not libc6:i386
p   sqlite3:i386 Provides  sqlite3            
p   sqlite3:i386 Depends   libc6:i386 (>= 2.4)
p   libc6:i386   Conflicts libc6-xen:i386     
p   libc6:i386   Provides  libc6-xen:i386
```

But I can not understand the meaning of the output.  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### aptitude's `why`

In short, `aptitude`'s `why` command try to say why a package should be installed or is installed in the system already. For example, in my system (Ubuntu 16.04) when I ran `aptitude why nautilus-data`, It says

```
i   unity-settings-daemon Depends nautilus-data (>= 2.91.3-1)
```

Which means `unity-settings-daemon` depends on `nautilus-data` and that's why it is installed, indicated by the `i` at the left most side column.

Again, when I ran `aptitude why edubuntu-desktop`, It says,

```
Unable to find a reason to install edubuntu-desktop.
```

Because none of my installed packages *depends* or *recommends* (*depends* and *recommends* are apt's internal term) `edubuntu-desktop`

#### aptitude's `why-not`

`why-not` is the opposite of `why`. It tries to find a reason why a given package should not be installed or should be removed if already installed.

For example, when I typed `aptitude why-not mate-power-manager:i386`, It says

```
i   mate-power-manager Conflicts mate-power-manager:i386
```

which means my installed `mate-power-manager:amd64` will conflict with `mate-power-manager:i386` (Because my system is a amd64 installation, that's why it didn't explicitly mention `amd64`).

The relevant part of the manual page is very clear. But including that will make the answer too long. Here is the [aptitude's manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/aptitude-curses.8.html)

---

#### About your problem

When you tried to install `libdbus-1-3:i386`, the messages here saying

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.10) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

the package `libdbus-1-3:i386` requires `libc6:i386 (>= 2.10)` but it cannot be installed. Also package `unity-control-center` depending on `libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0)` and `libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1)` cannot be installed.

The reason why cannot be installed can be many, including the specific version required for those packages are missing or will conflict with existing version installed etc.